# What's wrong with my translation from Linq Query Expression to Method-Based Query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have two Aggregate Roots: Student and Test, and each student could have 0..1 test. I am using EF Core 3.1 to perform a left outer join query to fetch students with her own test. Since the test could be null for a student, and EF Core dosen't support database GroupJoin, I write down my query as this:

```
    var studentsWithTest = from o in dbContext.Students
        join x in dbContext.Tests on o.TestId
            equals x.Id into tests
        from x in tests.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {o.Student, Test = x};
```

It works. However, what I am really interested is the equivalent method-based query performing the same fuction. I try to translate it as this:

```
    var studentsWithTest = dbContext.Students.SelectMany(o =>
        dbContext.Tests
            .Where(x => x.Id == o.TestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Select(x => new {o.Student, Test = x}));
```

But this code causes run-time Exception:

> Processing of the LINQ expression '(ProjectionBindingExpression:
> Student)' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed.
> This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.

Dose that mean I have made something wrong during the translation? Could you guys help me to figure that out? Thanks.

Comment: You should use a navigation property `Tests`in `Student`. Then you don't need any grouping statement, no `DefaultIfEmpty`, and the query becomes very simple.

Comment: You are right about the advantage.However, as independent aggregate roots, they should not refer to each other by entity, but should do with Id. It's DDD principle. And that's indeed more convenient to build clear domain models. And what I really care about here is the Linq syntax deep inside, not the EF Core practice. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The EF class model is not a domain model. Its primary task is data access and it should do that in the most convenient way thinkable. No DDD principles here. That's *also* separation of concerns.

Comment: Your viewpoint gives me some clue, I will think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this error, the [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433) in the error message will be the best explanation.

To solve this , add **ToList()** to `dbContext.Students`  as follow :

```
   var studentsWithTest = dbContext.Students.ToList().SelectMany(o =>
        dbContext.Tests
            .Where(x => x.Id == o.TestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Select(x => new {o.Student, Test = x}));
```

However, for the `one-to-one` relationship in ef core,you can also use **[Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)** is actually the easiest way, please refer to the following writing:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? TestId{ get; set; }
    public Test Test{ get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Linq:

```
    var studentsWithTest = dbContext.Students.Include(x => x.Tests)
                           .Select(x => new { x, Test = x.Tests });
```

---

### Update

As you comment said, you can try this code:

```
var  studentsWithTest = dbContext.Students
                  .SelectMany(o =>  dbContext.Tests.Where(x => x.Id == o.TestId).DefaultIfEmpty(), (o, x) => new
                  {
                      o.Student,
                      Test = x
                  });
```

You can also refer to [this](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/49552859/how-can-i-implement-a-left-outer-join-in-linq-using-lambda-syntax-on-entity-framework-core-2-0-).

Comment: Thank, the reason why I couldn't use navigation property is that I follow DDD patern, and stuents and tests are different aggregate roots

Comment: ToList() isn't a good solution as it will materialize all the data to the left of it from the database to memory, where it is subsequently filtered by the .Where() clause. The .Include() variant of the solution is correct and should be featured.

Comment: The point is how to translate the successful Query Expression to equivalent method-based query. According to "C# 8.0 in a Nutshell", all Query Expressions will be translated into method-based query and then be compiled. So what I want to know is how to achieve that manually, for better understanding of the mechanism.

Comment: @SillyJumper, yes, the linq statement here can indeed be translated into method-based query，instead of using select , you can use SelectMany's internal mechanism [`resultSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) to get the new result format,  I have updated my answer, hope it helps you

Comment: @Yu, Yes, it works. You are really helping! The key point is resultSelector, and that's the orverload I didn't know before. The links you supplied are also useful, thanks so much.